# inherit properties and then change some on particular site (css)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have three menus on this [test web site](http://vk.onalllevels.com/welcome). I am learning css and trying `menu2 & menu3` to `inherit all properties from menu class`. The second one looks bit different and is not clickable. I am happy with the 3rd one, just want to make it horizontal and change its position bit.

Could somebody tell me

- why the second menu is not click-able?
- how I can make the third menu vertical? I thought that `display: block;` for li of the 3rd menu would do the trick but I do not know the css path for that li.

Comment: Might I suggest the Firebug and Web Developer extensions for Firefox?
http://getfirebug.com/  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60

Comment: I am using firebug ... maybe I can use it better way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second menu isn't clickable because your third menu box is covering it, it's box even though you can't see it is the same size as the area covered by the double horizontal lines.

The third menu isn't vertical because the lis have float:left

Use the following css to correct

```
.menu3 li
{
float:none;
}
.menu3
{
position:absolute;
}
```

You will need to set the left/top options for the .menu3 to position it on the page where you want.

If you use firefox firebug you should install the web developer and firebug extensions. If you use safari you can enable the developer tools, if you use internet explorer 8 then you can also enable developer tools. (Firebug is the best in my opinion).

Comment: @Radek try right clicking an element in firefox then click inspect, hover over it in the firebug window and it should highlight blue so you can see what area it covers.

Comment: you're a genius! everything works fine. I didn't have to touch menu2 and it works now. I moved menu3 using `margin-left` and `margin-top` is that correct way? Could you elaborate in you your answer what `covering means`? Now is menu3 overlapping menu2 and it is clickable. Thank you so much for your fix

Comment: if I hover in firebug now, after the fix. Menu3 still overlaps menu2 but the colour is yellowish and menu2 works. So what is the difference to before the fix? Call me css baby.

Comment: @Radek in firebug blue means where the actual "box" that an object takes up is, yellow is the margins. I think purple is the padding. Before the blue took up the entire middle section which meant it was on top of the other elements. The further down the page an element is in your HTML the higher on top it will appear unless you apply a z-index with position in css.

Answer (score 0):

The second menu is not clickable because the third menu is covering it. One way to fix that is to remove `position: relative` from `.menu`.

The path for the `<li>`'s in the third menu is for example `.menu3 li`, but I am not really sure what you mean by making it vertical. I hope you can find out a way with this piece of information.

A little hint... A tool like FireBug for Firefox is of good help for CSS trial n erroring.